# Why is voltage input different from voltage output in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields

This is more specifically, when performing the meter bridge experiment. The meter bridge experiment is an experiment in which using the meter bridge, a jockey, voltmeter, battery eliminator, you keep changing the length of the wire(independent variable) and measure the voltage(dependent variable). You use this to plot a graph and calculate the electric field strength.

I set the battery eliminator to have 3V voltage. When I measured the voltage across the wire of length 1 metre, the voltage came out as 1 V? Why is this so? Using the formula Electric Field Strength = Voltage/ Length, the Electric Field Strength should be 3 NC^-1 but the value I got was 1 NC^-1

Comment: Could you provide a circuit diagram?

Comment: If the experiment is anything like what I have in mind, the proper quantity to use in all of this is electric potential/voltage, since the fields surrounding the wires etc. are neither homogenous nor easily characterized. The potentials/voltages in this resistive circuit, on the other hand, are easily measurable. What is the total voltage drop across the wire? 3V over 3m? In that case one would get a voltage drop of 1V/m (but don't mistake that for a field strength!). So if you are setting the rider at 1m, and the eliminator at 1V, the voltmeter should show zero. That's how we use a bridge.